# For video playback from cloud, would a properly written native mobile app be faster than a web app run on Android?

Tags: video-streaming

I want to develop a backend cloud service that delivers full color compressed videos (as high def as possible) to Android smart phones for streaming playback. Would I get better playback if I properly develop a native mobile app or if I simply use the browser, maybe with some scripting, to access and play the video? I want the highest bandwidth playback I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Video quality is determined by the used codec (plus the used options) and of the bitrate. Codecs should be implemented in hardware for efficiency reasons which limits the available codecs. I am not sure if in a web browser all codecs are available. If not this would be an advantage of the app. But this means of course that you have influence on the server side to decide which codec and bitrate to use. If you only can change the client side there is not much choice.

Comment: You might want to compare existing services like YouTube and other video sharing platforms which provide web app and mobile app.